# Issue with Regex characters to modify a string

Tags: regex, string, vb.net, replace

New to Stack Overflow.
Having issues trying to resolve Regex expression to modify the below:

Original string:

```
 753108944)))","0" 
"MULTIPOLYGON (((-7.7885889
```

Desired string:

```
753108944),(-7.7885889
```

I need to remove the   ))","0" & vbCrLf & "MULTIPOLYGON ((   from the string and having a extremely poor success rate, and I think its due to the . (period) being in there.
Have tried many regex replace configurations as well as standard string manipulation methods with no success.

Comment: You can also match them, e.g., `\(?[+-]?[^\D]\d?\.?\d+\)?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find and replace the following pattern, with *"),("*.

```
(?s)\){3}.+\({3}
```

Output

```
 753108944),(-7.7885889
```

Comment: Thanks Reilas, that works. I have spent hours on this. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

[Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace) will do what you are describing in your question:

```
Dim originalString As String = "753108944)))"",""0""" & vbCrLf & """MULTIPOLYGON (((-7.7885889"""
Dim processedString As String = originalString.Replace("))"",""0""" & vbCrLf & """MULTIPOLYGON ((", ",")
```

Comment: Thanks Etienne, that works as well. I need to brush up on my string manipulation and regex.